# Why is my loop not going through all values?

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I'm trying to get a Excel vba macro working. The code I'm using is the following :

```
Dim foo, bar, toto As Double
Dim nb As Integer
nb = 1

For bar = 1 To 1 Step 0.2
For toto = 1 To 4 Step 0.2
For foo = 1 To 2 Step 0.2
    Cells(nb, 1).Value = CStr("bar " & bar & " toto " & toto & " foo " & foo)
    nb = nb + 1
Next foo
Next toto
Next bar
End Sub
```

I would expect to see the case toto=4 printed. The end result I'm getting is :

```
bar 1 toto 1 foo 1
bar 1 toto 1 foo 1.2
bar 1 toto 1 foo 1.4
[....]
bar 1 toto 3.8 foo 1.6
bar 1 toto 3.8 foo 1.8
bar 1 toto 3.8 foo 2
```

Variable foo is going as expected from 1 to 2 and incrementing by 0.2 each times.
On the other hand, variable toto is going from 1 to 3.8 instead of going up to 4.

How can I change my code in order for toto to reach 4 ?
I tried changing the upper value of my for loops to (max + 1 step), and for toto it worked but for foo and bar their was an "extra" loop.

I tried to change the code to a while based approach, with no success either.

```
bar = 1
toto = 1
foo = 1
nb = 1

While (bar <= 1)
toto = 1
    While (toto <= 4)
    foo = 1
        While (foo <= 2)
        
        Cells(nb, 4).Value = CStr("bar " & bar & " toto " & toto & " foo " & foo)
        nb = nb + 1
        foo = foo + 0.2
        Wend
    toto = toto + 0.2
    Wend
bar = bar + 0.2
Wend
```

Comment: The explanation is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/floating-point-arithmetic-inaccurate-result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to floating-point error. I would avoid using `Step 0.2` and instead multiply `foo`, `bar`, and `toto` by `0.2` inside the loop, while only using whole numbers when looping:

```vb
Dim foo As Long, bar As Long, toto As Long, nb As Long

nb = 1

For bar = 1 To 5
    For toto = 1 To 20
        For foo = 1 To 10
            Cells(nb, 1).Value = CStr("bar " & bar * 0.2 & " toto " & toto * 0.2 & " foo " & foo * 0.2)
            nb = nb + 1
        Next
    Next
Next
```

Also note that in [vba](/questions/tagged/vba), `Dim foo, bar, toto As Double` only declares `toto` as `Double`. `foo` and `bar` are `Variant`s.

Comment: It seems that it is indeed a floating-point error. I tried to add a small value (1E-7) to the upper limit of each of my for loop, and it went smoothly. I'll wait for other answers, but I think I will be able to accept yours tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared your variables incorrectly. You need the `As` statement on every declaration. The way you did this makes `foo` and `bar` of type `Variant` which could be anything that VBA wants at the time. It's best to have one declaration per line. If we make the upper to be slightly greater than 4, like 4.01 then it works. I'm not sure why.

```
Dim foo As Double
Dim bar As Double 
Dim toto As Double
Dim nb As Integer
nb = 1

For bar = 1 To 1 Step 0.2
    For toto = 1 To 4.01 Step 0.2
        For foo = 1 To 2 Step 0.2
            Cells(nb, 1).Value = CStr("bar " & bar & " toto " & toto & " foo " & foo)
            nb = nb + 1
        Next foo
    Next toto
Next bar
```

If you don't like adding some slop to your upper limit on `toto` you can also force significant figures with `Round`.

This one works the way you would expect:

```
Sub test()
    Dim foo As Single
    Dim bar As Single
    Dim toto As Single
    Dim nb As Integer
    nb = 1
    
    For bar = 1 To 1 Step 0.2
        For toto = 1 To 4 Step 0.2
            toto = Round(toto, 1)
            For foo = 1 To 2 Step 0.2
                Debug.Print CStr("bar " & bar & " toto " & toto & " foo " & foo)
                nb = nb + 1
            Next foo
        Next toto
    Next bar
End Sub
```

Comment: The answer is floating-point error. We can't guarantee that stepping `0.2` will get us to exactly 4.

Comment: Changing to data type `Single` I see the error. It's reporting this: `bar 1 toto 3.800001 foo 1.8` which makes it overflow the 4 to 4.00000001 and it ends.

Comment: This can be fixed with `Round` too. Seems odd when math is the one thing computers are good at. Why would VBA be so sloppy?

Comment: I wouldn't call this "sloppy" at all.

Comment: You think it's normal or correct to add `0.200001` when asked to add `0.2`? because that is unacceptable in my industry.

Comment: Floating-point error is much broader than just VBA.